# OAuth2 auth server reusing the access token

Tags: authentication, server, oauth, oauth2

I found some implementations of **OAuth2** provider (auth server) which issues the **same access token** (for same user & scope) for different authentication request. Does the OAuth2 spec allows it?

Any side effects of using this implementation?